# "PermissionError: [Errno 13]" while trying to uninstall using pip uninstall

Tags: python

I'm new to both linux and python so I really can't figure out what is going on here. I was getting an Attribute error in my script, which some searching suggests it's to do with the requests version I am using, and just wanted to reinstall requests for python but I am now getting this error. I know I probably made a mistake using "pip" to install instead of "pip3" and it looks like doing so gave me a slightly older or incorrect version. I just want to be able to get rid of the requests version I have and install the newest one. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[full error in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW0RH.png)

Comment: It probably means the user you run pip as doesn't have permission to rename/delete the file.  stat the file.   Post the error here instead of linking to an external site.

Comment: Any chance you installed `requests` as root, either explicitly as root or with `sudo pip install requests`? Or did you install `requests` with your distro's package manager: `apt`, `yum` etc.?

Answer (score -1):

You don't have permission to uninstall it, and you need to use Sudo.

```
sudo pip uninstall requests
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work since, for some reason, "sudo pip" is not a recognized command. I'm assuming there may be something wrong in my path to cause this. Either way, I ended up just finding all associated files with requests, removing them, and was then able to install it properly. I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: Sorry that it didn't work. I highly recommend you use virtualenv(https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) to avoid the same issues in the future for the other packages.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep that in mind next time. As I said in the description, I am still very new to linux and coding in general so I don't always know the best practices for a lot of cases. Thanks again